# How to split line which has multple repeating texts

Tags: python, string

I have a string

```
"abcabdfailedTestefgfailedTestsdfailedTest"
```

I need to split this line on basis of `failedTest`

tried using `split()` but no luck.

Comment: what is desired output?

Comment: Need this into multiple lines

Comment: You should show your attempt and explain what "no luck" entails

Comment: @Thonas1601, Do you want this : `import re; print(re.sub(r'(failedTest)', r'\1\n', yout_string))`

Answer (score 0):

If `failedTest` is the keyword that can be removed, you could replace `failedTest` with the linebreak character `\n` like this:

```
s = "abcabdfailedTestefgfailedTestsdfailedTest"
s_newline = s.replace('failedTest', '\n')
```